# jQuery window resize and Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, cross-browser, css-float

I can't solve a problem I'm having with the resizing of a menu. The code I'm going to post don't work on Chrome only.

Being a difficult situation to explain by words, I'll show you some screenshots of problem.

This is my menu looks at the opening:

[image]

When I resize the browser's window <=605px, the jQuery code remove the left floating, and so the items are put in column and centered. (sorry, I can't post more than 2 links)

When I resize it > 605 it should look like in the first image (and it actually works on i.e. and firefox), but on chrome it appears like this:

[image]

Here's the code.

HTML:

```
<div id="containerMenu">

    <div id="menu">

        <ul>

            <a href="index.html"><li>HOME</li></a>
            <li>SERVIZI</li>
            <a href="wedding.html"><li>WEDDING</li></a>
            <a href="food.html"><li>FOOD</li></a>
            <a href="contatti.html"><li>CONTATTI</li></a>

        </ul>

    </div>

</div>
```

CSS (only the usefull things):

```
#containerMenu {width:100%;
    text-align:center;}

#menu {display:inline-block}

#menu li {float: left;}
```

jQuery:

```
$(window).resize(function() 
    {
    if($(window).innerWidth() <= 605) 
        { 
        $("li", $("#menu")).css("float","none")
        }

    else 
        {                   
        $("li", $("#menu")).css("float","left")
        }                   
    })
```

Of course I've the code to let it happen even if the window is not resized, but only opened with a width <= 605, but it's exactly the same of the one above, just without the .resize() event.

Can you help me to make this code compatible with google chrome?

Thank you,
Stefano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you could handle this kind of thing with jQuery, it would be much much simpler to add a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to your CSS. Something similar to

```
/* Your normal css */
#containerMenu {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
#menu {
    display:inline-block
}
#menu li {
    float: left;
}

/* Media query */
@media (max-width: 605px) {
    #menu li {
        float: none;
    }
}
```

This will work across all browsers seamlessly. What's going on behind the scenes here: You're telling the browser that you want the list items for the menu to be `float: left`. But after that, you're adding an exception with a `max-width` of 605px, ie if the browser window is 605px or less, you actually want the list items for the menu to be `float: none`. That's about my understanding of what you would like your JavaScript to do.

Media queries are one of the foundations for [Responsive Web Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design).